# Check if shapefiles exists in folder

Tags: arcpy, shapefile

In ArcGIS modelbuilder I want to check if a shapefiles exists, if not I want to create the shapefile in that folder. I guess the calculate value tool within ArcGIS modelbuilder can be used, but I need some python scripting to do the work.

Any idea or python script examples?

Answer (score 8):

I think you want the [`arcpy.Exists`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exists/000v00000021000000/) function:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\temp"
>>> if arcpy.Exists("Cameron.shp"):
...     print "Exists"
...
Exists
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Chad Chopper is right. You can also use `ValidateTableName()` function which can determine whether a specific name is valid and unique to a specific workspace.

> The Exists() function can check to see whether the table name is
>   unique for  a given workspace.

The difference between `ValidateTableName()` and `Exists()` is that The `ValidateTableName()` function does not determine that the specified name is unique to the specified workspace. It only returns a valid table name for that workspace.

**Example Code:**

```
# Move all shapefiles from a folder into a geodatabase
#
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the workspace. List all of the shapefiles
#
env.workspace = "D:/St_Johns"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")

# Set the workspace to SDE for ValidateTableName
#
env.workspace = "Database Connections/Bluestar.sde"

# For each feature class name
#
for fc in fcs: 
    # Validate the output name so it is valid
    #
    outfc = arcpy.ValidateTableName(fc)

    # Copy the features from the workspace to a geodatabase
    #
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outfc)
```

you can get more info [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z00000020000000)...

Answer (score 0):

For a pure python solution, you can use [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check if the shapefile exists and is indeed a file.

```
import os

myfile = r'C:\temp\myshp.shp'

if os.path.isfile(myfile):
    print "The file exists"
    # Do something
```